# Do SVG-enabled browsers ignore alternative images (when included in object tags)?

Tags: html, svg, vector-graphics, object-tag

An illustration that I want to include in a site is 28.1 times smaller in SVG format than the same illustration saved as a PNG.

Unfortunately, I have to cater for browsers that aren't SVG-enabled. So I'm still including the PNG as an alternative, like so:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="illustration.svg">
  <img src="illustration.png" alt="alternate description">
</object>
```

Will SVG enabled browsers ignore the PNG in this case or will it still get loaded in the background somehow? (i.e. am I saving on overall load time?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Firefox v4 and Chrome v10 **download** the alternate image. You will not be saving any bandwidth or load time by using an SVG image with PNG fallback.

Tested by loading [this page](http://phrogz.net/svg/svg_via_object_with_png_fallback.xhtml) and looking at the Net panel in Firebug and Chrome's Developer Tools:
[image: Firebug showing requests for both tiger.svg and tiger.png]
[image: Chrome's Developer Tools showing requests for both tiger.svg and tiger.png]

Note that this does not mean that using the SVG is not a good idea. You should still use the SVG, as it will print and scale better than the corresponding PNG.

Comment: You could use a conditional comment, so only IE gets the png. Sure, there's Opera, and perhaps some mobile browsers, but how much of your market are they?

Comment: This answer is so insightful. Wish I could give you more than one Up-vote!

Comment: @Phrogz: should this be reported as a bug?

Answer (score 1):

I used something like that:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="...">
   <!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <img src="img/circle.png" alt="" />
   <![endif]-->
</object>
```

Internet Explorer < 9 can't display SVG, so it gets the PNG. Almost all other browers can handle the SVG and don't need the fallback.

Answer (score 0):

With [Jquery SVG](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html) plugin:

```
$(selector).svg({ 
loadURL: '', // External document to load 
onLoad: null, // Callback once loaded 
settings: {}}) // Additional settings for SVG element
```

try and catch it, and onFail load the image. :)